# Cargar y leer archivo .CSV

Tags: python

me gustaría poder seleccionar que archivo .CSV cargar para después graficarlo. Cargo el archivo .CSV con el siguiente código.

```
def abrir():
return filedialog.askopenfilename()
```

Antes leía los archivos .CSV con el código:

```
def lineas():
datos = []
with open("ejemplo.csv") as fname:
    lineas = fname.readlines()
for linea in lineas:
    datos.append(linea.strip('\n'))
return datos
```

Pero ahora no soy capaz de leer el archivo seleccionado.
Gracias.

Comment: `with open(abrir()) as fname:`

Comment: Si quieres graficarlo lo mejor es usar pandas

Answer (score 0):

Un pequeño ejemplo con pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

archivos_csv=(glob.glob("ejemplo.csv"))
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(archivos_csv)
for index, row in data_frame.iterrows():
    datos=pd.read_csv(str(row[0]), delimiter=',', header=[0])   
    print(datos)
plt.boxplot(datos)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hola buenas, cuando ejecuto tu código me da el siguiente error:                            `chunks = self._reader.read_low_memory(nrows)`                                                                   `File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 801, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read_low_memory`                                                               `File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 857, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows`           Perdón si no salen bien escritos los errores, hay más pero no me entran por los caracteres.